# Mods and Multiplicative functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

Where m is the largest odd factor of n, I am trying to prove that $$\sigma(n)\equiv d(m)\mod{2}$$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I presume $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$. Then $\sigma(n)\equiv\sigma(m)\pmod2$ as one can ignore even divisors of $n$. For
odd $m$, $\sigma(m)\equiv d(m)\pmod2$ as all divisors of $m$ are odd.

Comment: What do you mean "ignore even divisors of n"?

Comment: @GwenDi When working modulo $2$ one can ignore anything even.